# Auto generated codes in Code First Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to learn Code First Migration . I wonder why temporary codes generated in the migration folder is not removed after doing a successful migration? Since I have updated my database schema and my models what is the point to store those codes in migration folder?

Comment: what you mean by temporary codes in migration folder ?

Comment: If you means the classes like 201502061158185_initial.cs  which are inherite from DbMigration so they are not temporary. This classes are generated for you from the model you have. You could also just write those classes by yourself and apply migrations with update-datebase.

Comment: Yes I mean those classes (201502061158185_initial.cs). Why these classes are not removed after a successful migration? Whats the point to keep them in my project when my schema and model both are updated successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the migration files created in the solution, you will find a method called Down(). In case you wish to downgrade the changes you can use this migration file again. Moreover, migration files can be used to create a fresh new database, say moving to production after finishing the development.